# Install Server in UBUNTU Desktop 17.04

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, mapserver, ubuntugis

My last question here was **" [Install webpage Admin in Ubuntu GIS (Server)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241835/install-webpage-admin-in-ubuntu-gis-server) "** but i´m trying to do something new while i´m waiting for the possible answers:

- I have Windows 10 in PC (With **QGIS 2.18.7** and **PostgreSQL 4v1** installed) and i installed **Virtual Box** to run **UBUNTU Desktop 17.04** as you can see:

[image]

- My question is: **What is the best spatial data server I can use in ubuntu to allow connection to Postgresql?**

NB: With a friendly work environment.

I have read it:

a) **https://geoind.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/r-e-rstudio-no-ubuntu/**

b) **http://www.oslandia.com/full-spatial-database-power-in-2-lines-en.html**

c) **https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Wms**

d) **https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuGIS**

Answer (score 0):

Your question "What is the best spatial data server I can use in ubuntu to allow connection to Postgresql?" is not really specific enough.

Do you mean, what is the best way to get data out of Postgresql in terms of open spatial standards? The answer to that is [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) or [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/).

If you want to just get it on a simple map? Use [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/).

If you mean from a purely server-side framework? Try [Psocopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) or [Psocopg-PostGIS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg-postgis) in a Python script, and if you want that in an API that you write, perhaps use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

But your actual question suggests that you don't know exactly what you want to do, so, go get experimenting with all these links I've sent!